# Remove keys without data from Info.plist

Tags: swift, xcode, plist

I have an iOS app that has the following key in Info.plist

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(MYAPP_EXTERNAL_ACCESSORIES)</string>
    </array>
```

We have a client and merchant version of the app, only the latter gets a value assigned here (a bluetooth printer). When archiving for the client, we get the following error during the process of uploading to iTunes Connect:

```
ERROR ITMS-90110: "This bundle is invalid. The key UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols in the Info.plist file must be an array of non-empty strings."
```

I found ways to change Info.plist using a script (adding/removing something from an existing key) but not how to remove a key completely for some build configurations, or if it is empty.

What would be the best solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you use to have your different version of your app? 2 targets? 2 schemes? If its only depending on build configuration you can duplicate your plist and select the appropriate one in your build settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicate you already know how to work with a build script. The tool you want to use in your script is `plutil`:

```
plutil -insert <keypath> -<type> <value> <path_to_file>
```

or

```
plutil -remove <keypath> <path_to_file>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely try this out soon! For now I did it the other way: remove the key from the .plist and add it (using Fastlane) if needed.